# Obtain GET_REQUEST string in JavaScript for CGI script

Tags: javascript, ajax, get, cgi

I want to run a CGI script from JS without modifying a CGI file.
One straightforward option is to get parameters of the GET_REQUEST: `...cgi?paremeters` and then insert this string in XMLHttpRequest's `open("GET","...cgi?paremeters",true);`.
Is it possible to get the URL with parameters without running some heavy JS code?
For example, in perl CGI it is very simple with `$cgi->param('ID_of_node')`

[image]

MWE:

```
<html>
<head>test<head>
<script>
function runCGI() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){ 
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
    }

    var parameters = getQueryString(); // How to get it?
    xmlhttp.open("GET","perl.cgi?parameters",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="runCGI()">Run</button>
<p id="output">output</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: whould it be possible to do with `action="runCGI()"` and `method='get'`?

Comment: It is, you could do: `action="javascript: runCGI()"` or `<form action="" onsubmit="runCGI(); return false;">` but inline JS is not very clean, IMHO.